# Module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd 
import dateutil

# Load data from csv file
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('phone_data.csv')
# Convert date from string to date times
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=True)
```

The above code causes the error:
"module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'"

I'm new to Python and am attempting to use this tutorial:
[Summarising, Aggregating, and Grouping data in Python Pandas](https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/)

Any suggestions on what could be causing the error? I've noticed others have had the same question, but the proposed solutions don't seem to apply in my case.

Comment: Did you name the script you're writing `pandas.py` by any chance?

Comment: No, I didn't name it pandas.py.

Comment: Hey OP, couple troubleshooting questions here: Can you post everything in the folder you're doing this in, along with the full directory structure/name of this file?

Comment: This is the path: C:\pythonapps\dateutil.py

Comment: I'm running from a command line - C:\>python C:\pythonapps\dateutil.py

Comment: I'm running from C:\. I thought I might try running from a different folder. I had thought that the import pandas line would make that unnecessary. Am I wrong?

Comment: Another debugging question: Can you add `print(pd.__file__)` to your script? What is the output of that print statement?

Comment: The folder you're running from shouldn't matter. will you run `dir C:\pythonapps\` and print output?

Comment: The contents of the folder: dateutil.py,
Python apps.py,
<DIR> _pycache_ > dateutil.cpython-36.pyc

Comment: I don't know how the folder  _pycache_ was installed. Python apps.py is another script I've written.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonapps\dateutil.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\delliott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\pythonapps\dateutil.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('phone_data.csv')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: I see that I import that dateutil folder in the script. I wasn't sure at first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright OP, figured this one out. Not exactly sure *why* this is the case, but it's because of what you named your file. Somehow naming your script `dateutil.py` and importing dateutil/pandas is causing a problem.

I got the same error locally until I renamed it. Try renaming your file to something like `myfile.py` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Yes. That's it. I renamed the file and no longer get the error.  I had earlier renamed the file dateutilagain.py and still got the error. It must not have liked "dateutil" in the file name. It works with "myfile.py" and probably anything else without "dateutil" in the name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad we could work it out! Sounds like some sort of name collision.

Comment: Similar problem for me -- I had foolishly named my file csv.py which is a name conflict inside the pandas module and caused me to have the same error.  After uninstalling and reinstalling pandas and it still didn't work, I looked here and sure enough, you need to avoid using any of the module names as filenames in your project.